# PHP read object attributes

Tags: php, attributes, stdclass

I have an Object name `obj` like that:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [@attributes] => stdClass Object
        (
            [CurrencyCode] => AUD
            [CurrencyName] => AUST.DOLLAR
            [Buy] => 17825.4
            [Transfer] => 17933
            [Sell] => 18092.95
        )
)
```

I use some ways:

- `obj[CurrencyCode]`
- `obj ->CurrencyCode`

but don't work and get error: `Use of undefined constant CurrencyCode`
If use:
`obj -> @attributes` to get error: `syntax error, unexpected ''@attributes'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap the `@attributes` in the `{}`
Check the example

```
<?php
 $abc = array('@attributes' => array('CURR' => 1));
$abc = json_decode(json_encode($abc));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($abc->{"@attributes"}->CURR);
?>
```